# Integration by Change of Variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

By using change of variable,
$$x+y=(\surd2)u \text { and } y-x=(\surd2)v$$

Evaluate $$I=\iint(y-x)^2e^{-(x+y)^2}dv\,du$$

with $R$ bounded by $x=0,y=0,x+y=1$

After changing of variable, I get
$$\int_0^{1/\surd2}\int_{-u}^u2v^2e^{-2u^2}dv\,du=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^{1/\surd2}u^3e^{-2u^2}\,du$$

I cannot solve the equation after that part. Help me check which part I made mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=-2u^2$.  Then, $u\,du = -\frac{1}{4}dt$ so that
\begin{align}
\frac{4}{3}\int_0^{1/\surd2}u^3e^{-2u^2}\,du &= 
 \frac{4}{3}\int_0^{1/\surd2}u^2e^{-2u^2}\,u\,du \\
 &= 
 \frac{4}{3} \int_0^{-1} \left(-\frac{1}{2}t\right)\,e^t  \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)dt \\
 &= \frac{1}{6}\int_0^{-1} t\,e^t \, dt.
\end{align}
This last integral can be done by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Use $w = u^2$. Then $dw = 2u\  du$ so

$$\frac{4}{3 \dot\  2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}  w e^{-2w} dw $$

Now use integration by parts. I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Best not to re-use $v$ though.